# Latex changes fonts in Matlab produced eps files

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex, matlab-figure, eps

**In short:**

1. I produce a figure in matlab (2013a). The problem lies with the `"fontname"` command. Example code is

   ```
   plot([1:10],[1:10])
   set(gca, 'XTick',[0,4,8])
   set(gca, 'XTicklabel',{'p/2','3p/2','2p'},'fontname','symbol');
   ```
2. Prints it with `print -despc "filename"`.
3. Include it in a latex file with `includegraphics` command and `epstopdf`
4. The fonts in the figure are distorted, while they are intact the eps file itself. For example, in the latex file, the `pi` labels are turned into not-equal signs.

Do you know why does this happen?

*Remark:* I have to use `"fontname"` command because, at least for Matlab 2013a, latex interpreter can not be applied for the `XTickLabel`.

Comment: I know this does not really solve the mentioned problem directly - but indirectly. Instead of doing your own workflow to get MATLAB figures into your latex document, you could use: https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz I also used it in my thesis and it is very special and awesome (I'm not doing ads here, I'm not the author). See here to get an example ("What you’ll be creating"): http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/

Comment: This question is better asked on tex.stackexchange.com.